# how to make example.com/eat load example.com/eat.php?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I know that it is trying to load the .html version, i am pretty sure at least. I also think that it is something in an .htaccess file. I have tried a few different things from searching google and come up short. Basically i want it to work so that if there is no .html file by the name entered, it will go to the php one.

Is this possible?

Comment: You are either looking for URL rewriting (very flexible) or setting a default page (specifies the order in which the web server attempts to locate a page). If you google those terms, you will find help, such as: http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -s
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L,QSA]
```

The above rules say, if the requested file is of 0 size, or does not exist as a file, symbolic link, or directory and a file of the same name with a `.php` extension exists, then rewrite to the `.php` file.

This effectively rewrites `site.com/foo` to `site.com/foo.php` where `foo` can be anything.

I'm not quite clear on what you want.  If you want to map non-existant `.html` files to a `.php` extension, try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

This just says if the requested file does not exist and ends in `.html`, then grab the file name (less the `.html`) and try to rewrite to the `.php` extension.

Comment: will these work in all directories too? like would site.com/foo/bar go to site.com/foo/bar.php

Comment: also, how would i make it work for subdirectories. Say, foo.bar/eat --> foo.bar/eat.php

Comment: `.htaccess` files are inherited by any child directories that don't have a `.htaccess` file so it should work for subfolders/subdomains.

Comment: i have your first code block in my .htaccess file.. and i am getting a page unfound error. try here: staging.easyzag.com/eat (try the .php version and see it is there)

Comment: in that case try adding an htaccess with that same content to the staging directory and see if that helps, or is it already in that folder directly?

Comment: put it in the folder directly as well

Answer (score 1):

In htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^eat$ eat.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

Add this to apache configuration (either in `httpd.conf`, `VirtualHost` config, or in `.htaccess`):

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Using rewriting for this is an overkill, when `content-negotiation` can do the job.

Comment: i am using godaddy for hosting, is there a way to change my apache config through them do you think?

Comment: you can set this in `.htaccess` (it is per-dir apache configuration)

Comment: i have your code in my .htaccess file.. and i am getting a page unfound error. try here: staging.easyzag.com/eat (try the .php version and see it is there)

Comment: what else do you have in `.htaccess` ?